# Como selecionar palavras padronizadas usando Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Eu quero validar essa regex:

```
- regex.test.test.test.test
- -regex.test.test.test.test
- +regex.test.test.test.test
```

- Se tirar um traço do começo até a palavra, quero que essa regex seja
  invalidada.
- Se não houver ponto entre palavras dentro dessa cadeia, que seja
  invalidada também.
- Ou seja, o traço, o ponto, o sinal de `+`, é tudo uma estrutura que
  tem que ser colocada de forma correta, como acima. Caso mude a forma padrão, essa regex não será mais válida.

Ou seja, isso é infinito, por exemplo, se eu colocar milhares de pontos, mas somente um pontinho está mudado, que seja invalidado tudo.

Eu estava tentando aqui, mas a forma como eu faço é finita e parece conter muitos erros.

```
(-\s{1}\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+)|(-\s{1}-\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+)|(-\s{1}[+]\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+)
```

Como faço para gerar a estrutura dessa regex, podendo ela ser infinita e somente válida com estrutura correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar esta regex:

```
^- [-+]?\w+(\.\w+)*$
```

Se a estrutura é rígida, melhor usar os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que ela só tem o que está na regex.

Depois do `^` temos o hífen seguido de um espaço.

Depois temos `[-+]`, que significa "o caractere `-` **ou** o caractere `+`". E o `?` logo depois torna este trecho [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (ou seja, pode ou não ter o `-` ou o `+`).

Logo depois temos `\w+` (uma ou mais ocorrências de [letras, dígitos ou o caractere `_`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)).

A seguir, temos `(\.\w+)*`. Entre parênteses temos um ponto seguido de um ou mais `\w`. E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, a sequência "ponto seguido de `\w+`" pode se repetir de zero a infinitas vezes.

Se quiser obrigar que tenha pelo menos um ponto seguido de `\w+`, troque o `*` por `+`:

```
^- [-+]?\w+(\.\w+)+$
```

Assim, a sequência "ponto seguido de `\w+`" precisa aparecer pelo menos uma vez.

---

Se quiser quantidades específicas, troque o `+` por uma das opções abaixo:

- `{1,10}`: entre 1 e 10 ocorrências
- `{10}`: exatamente 10 ocorrências
- `{3,}`: no mínimo 3 ocorrências (sem limite máximo)

Adapte os valores de acordo com o que você precisar. Ex:

```
^- [-+]?\w+(\.\w+){3,}$
```

Assim, a sequência "ponto seguido de `\w+`" precisa se repetir no mínimo 3 vezes.

---

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/JWJIDD/1/) um exemplo da regex funcionando.

---

Obs: o ponto possui significado especial em regex (significa ["qualquer caractere"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), então se quisermos apenas o próprio caractere "ponto", precisamos escrevê-lo como `\.`

Comment: Fantastico a simplicidade